# Approximation of e in java

Tags: java, for-loop

I am trying to get approximation of constant e where e = 2 + 1/2! + 1/3! + 1/4! + .......
every time I run the code I always! get 2. I would appreciate it if you could correct my code :)

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class E
{
  public static void main (String[] args)
  {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);

    System.out.println("How many iterations");

    //n = iterations
    int n = scan.nextInt();

    long factor =1;  //starts at 1
    long e = 1;   //e starting point


    for (int i=1; i<=n; i++) 
    {
      factor = factor * i;
      e +=  1/factor;
    }

    System.out.println(e);

  }
}
```

Comment: You have `e` as a `long`. This is an integral value...

Answer (score 3):

You are performing integer division, which in Java, truncates any decimal result so that the result is always an integer.  This is the line:

```
e +=  1/factor;
```

That is causing you to add `0` many times, which isn't what you need here.

Use a `double` literal `1.0` to force floating-point calculation.

```
e +=  1.0/factor;
```

Also, mathematically *e* is not an integer (it's irrational and transcendental), so `long` is an inappropriate data type to use.  Declare `e` to be `double`.

After these changes, this is the output I get:

```
How many iterations
20
2.7182818284590455
```

Comment: If you want to be any more precise, you could switch to BigDecimal arithmetic. `BigDecimal e ...; ...  e = e.add(new BigDecimal(1).divideBy(factor))` and so on and so forth.

Comment: @geert3 And use a higher number of iterations.